# How can i add a point at a place where i clicked?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Does anyone know how to add a point where the mouse position is clicked?
Using the Typescript (or) JavaScript code.

I think for some how I know the solution but I don't know how to implement it. The thing that I know is how to get the X co-ordinates and Y co-ordinates at that particular point and the thing that I don't know is how to implement that.

```
    function getClickPosition(e) {
     var xPosition = e.clientX;
     var yPosition = e.clientY;
    }
```

Comment: When you say 'a point' do you mean an actual html element?

Comment: You can do it by dynamically appending divs to some element on the page. Here I've created sample:
https://jsbin.com/dofuyafice/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick approach is demonstrated by the snippet

```js
function getClickPosition(e) {
  var p = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  }
  drawAt(p);
  return p
}

function drawAt(point) {
  var dotSize = 10; // in px
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.backgroundColor = "#000"
  div.style.width = dotSize + "px";
  div.style.height = dotSize + "px"
  div.style.position = "absolute"
  div.style.left = (point.x - dotSize / 2) + "px"
  div.style.top = (point.y - dotSize / 2) + "px"
  div.style.borderRadius = "50%"
  root.appendChild(div);
}

document.getElementById("root").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  getClickPosition(e);
})
```

```html
<div id="root" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; background-color: #ccc"></div>
```

however, you might wanna look into the HTML canvas

Comment: Nice, additionally if you want it on mousedown/mouseup instead of click (draw) you could do it like https://jsbin.com/xobiqedasa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Also consider scroll position.

Comment: Wow! The above code solved my issue really thank you man.......... for your help.

Comment: @NaveenKumar yo welcome